# Bash argument autocomplete

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm writing a bash to process files in a directory. I have some base (quite long) path in which to process. I want to specify via option and argument a sub-path and make it autocompletable. I mean something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=~/path/to/base/dir

while getopts ":d:" opt; do
    case $opt in
      d)
         dir=$dir/$OPTARG
         ;;
      #invalid input handling
    esac
done
```

But in this implementation the argument is not autocompletable and I have to type all the name of a sub-directory myself (`Tab` doesn't work).

Is there a way to achieve this in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to implement path-completion from a custom base-directory specified by a command-line option-flag. Here is a small example illustrating how to accomplish this. First I'm going to slightly modify your example script to make the demonstration slightly more interesting (i.e. to produce output):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# echo_path.sh
#
#    Echoes a path.
#

# Parse command-line options
while getopts ":d:" opt; do

    # Use '-d' to specify relative path
    case "${opt}" in
    d)
        directory="${OPTARG}"
        ;;
    esac
done

# Print the full path
echo "$(readlink -f ${directory})"
```

This is essentially the same as your example script, but it prints out the given argument.

Next we need to write a function to be called by the Bash programmatic-completion system. Here is a script which defines such a function:

```bsh
# echo_path_completion.bash

# Programmatic path completion for user specified file paths.

# Define a base directory for relative paths.
export BASE_DIRECTORY=/tmp/basedir

# Define the completion function
function _echo_path_completion() {

    # Define local variables to store adjacent pairs of arguments
    local prev_arg;
    local curr_arg;

    # If there are at least two arguments then we have a candidate
    # for path-completion, i.e. we need the option flag '-d' and
    # the path string that follows it.
    if [[ ${#COMP_WORDS[@]} -ge 2 ]]; then

        # Get the current and previous arguments from the command-line
        prev_arg="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}";
        curr_arg="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";

        # We only want to do our custom path-completion if the previous
        # argument is the '-d' option flag
        if [[ "${prev_arg}" = "-d" ]]; then

            # We only want to do our custom path-completion if a base
            # directory is defined and the argument is a relative path
            if [[ -n "${BASE_DIRECTORY}" && ${curr_arg} != /* ]]; then

                # Generate the list of path-completions starting from BASE_DIRECTORY
                COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -d -o default -- "${BASE_DIRECTORY}/${curr_arg}") );

                # Don't append a space after the command-completion
                # This is so we can continue to apply completion to subdirectories
                compopt -o nospace;

                # Return immediately
                return 0;
            fi
        fi
    fi

    # If no '-d' flag is given or no base directory is defined then apply default command-completion
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -o default -- "${curr_arg}") );
    return 0;
}

# Activate the completion function
complete -F _echo_path_completion echo_path
```

Now let's source our completion script:

```bsh
source echo_path_completion.bash
```

Let's make our script executable and move it to somewhere in our PATH:

```bsh
chmod +x echo_path.bash
mv -i echo_path.bash /usr/local/bin
```

And finally, let's add an alias for our script which doesn't have a file extension:

```bsh
alias echo_path=echo_path.bash
```

Now if you enter `echo -d` and hit the tab button then you should get file-path completion starting from the BASE_DIRECTORY. To test this out you could try the following:

```bsh
mkdir -p ${BASE_DIRECTORY}
mkdir -p "${BASE_DIRECTORY}/file"{1..5}
```

When you hit tab you should get the following list of completions:

```
user@host:~$ echo_path -d
user@host:~$ echo_path -d /tmp/basedir/file
/tmp/basedir/file1  /tmp/basedir/file2  /tmp/basedir/file3  /tmp/basedir/file4  /tmp/basedir/file5
```

Notice that after the first tab the string is converted to an absolute path. You can change this if you want, but I think this is might be the preferable behavior.

Here are some references you can consult for more information.

For official references, take a look at following sections of the Bash manual:

- [Section: 5.2 Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) (look for variables with the `COMP_` prefix)
- [Section 8.7: Programmable Completion Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins)

Also look at the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide from the Linux Documentation Project:

- [Appendix J. An Introduction to Programmable Completion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html)

For a quick introduction to some features of programmatic completion in Bash, see this post from "The Geek Stuff" site:

- [10 Useful Linux Bash_Completion Complete Command Examples (Bash Command Line Completion on Steroids)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/bash-completion-complete/)

There are also several related StackOverflow posts that you might find useful:

- [Custom Bash Autocomplete with File Path Completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778261/custom-bash-autocomplete-with-file-path-completion)
- [specify another directory to compgen for auto completing directories, than using pwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700011/specify-another-directory-to-compgen-for-auto-completing-directories-than-using)
- [Bash tab completion adds extra space after the first completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981764/bash-tab-completion-adds-extra-space-after-the-first-completion)
- [Conditional trailing space with bash programmable completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129747/conditional-trailing-space-with-bash-programmable-completion)