# Bash auto-completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm trying to figure out how autocompletion works. I read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322047/bash-argument-autocomplete) and the whole bash reference on `complete`, `compgen` and `compopt`, but this doesn't tell me how they really work together.

I'm trying to create an auto-completion for a command that takes a verb (from a rather small set) followed by the name of an existing file. So far I have this:

```
verbs=(upload download delete)

function ac_complete {
    printf "COMP_WORDS[%d/%d]: "  ${COMP_CWORD} ${#COMP_WORDS[@]}
    printf "[%s] " "${COMP_WORDS[@]}"
    printf "\n"
    
    if [[ COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]] 
    then 
        COMPREPLY=( "${verbs[@]}" )
    else
        compopt -o default
    fi
}

complete -F ac_complete testit
```

but it doesn't work, I never see bash completing the verb.

- How are possible completions returned?
- What should be returned? Only those still valid at that point (ie, after a "d", should the set be "upload"/"download"/"delete" or only "download"/"delete" (if so there is a quick way to apply that restriction?)?

The completion for the file works, but I'd like to restrict it to few filetypes...

Comment: You could try [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/), they both have IMHO an even better autocompletion than `bash`

Comment: On my target system I'm lucky I'm allowed to use bash...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [bash_completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/tree/master/completions) package for examples.

The most common way to generate completions is to call `compgen` to build the `COMPREPLY` array. Figure out what arguments are valid this particular context, then translate that a `compgen` call. The `compgen` builtin filters arguments that aren't completions of the specified prefix. For example:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${verbs[*]}" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") )
```

`compgen` is the step that figures out that to complete `d`, only `download` and `delete` are valid.

For files, use `compgen -G "*.ext"` to restrict the completion to files with the extension `.ext`. This simple idiom breaks on file names with spaces (or wildcard characters). The [`_filedir` function from `bash_completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/2.10/bash_completion#L547) handles file names in a more robust way (which still breaks on newlines and wildcard characters): `_filedir '*.ext'`.

Comment: So the gist of autocompletion is that `COMPREPLY` is an array of possible completions, and the `comp*` buil-ins are mostlly easy ways to generate these completions? How are spaced handled? Your answer doesn't seem to support spaces in verbs (curve ball, I know). Your file completion woudl also list all the files, I had to change it to `compgen -G "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}*.txt"` to have the expected completions, but this still doesn't work if there are files with spaces in the filename.

Comment: @xenoid Sorry, that's more advanced than my bash knowledge (I use zsh). As far as I can tell, to deal with spaces in file names, use `local IFS=$'\n'` in your completion function. To deal with newlines or wildcard characters in file names, use zsh.

Comment: @xenoid Ah, looking at examples from `bash_completion`: use its `_filedir` function.

Comment: OK works great. Thx